# Unable to resolve symbol: Example in this context clojure 1.10

Tags: clojure

I am a beginner with Clojure and I received this error while trying to write code in Clojure:

```clj
; Syntax error compiling at (src/com/playground/core.clj:17:1).
; Unable to resolve symbol: Example in this context
```

Here is my code

```clj
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

;; This program displays Hello World
(defn Example []
   ;; The below code declares a integer variable
  (def x 1)

   ;; The below code declares a float variable
  (def y 1.25)

   ;; The below code declares a string variable
  (def str1 "Hello")
  (println x)
  (println y)
  (println str1))
(Example)
```

I pulled this directly from tutorialspoint and tried to find other people who had the same error but could not find anybody else.

Comment: If you see def inside defn and this is from a site, that claims to teach Clojure: run! This is no idiomatic Clojure and no good advice to write Clojure code.

Comment: I agree with @cfrick, this is shockingly poor quality for a tutorial and should be revised. I suggest following a peer recommended tutorial, such as [Clojure by Example](https://kimh.github.io/clojure-by-example) or [Clojure for the Brave and True](https://www.braveclojure.com/)

Comment: Agree with @cfrick's comment. Would you update your question to show how you are running this code?  If I click on the "Live Demo" link at Tutorialspoint for this example, it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't evaluate that function. Open REPL for this project, evaluate definition for `Example` and then evaluate `(Example)`.

As you can already see in comments, this code is very bad and you shouldn't learn from that tutorial. But from a beginner point of view, it may be helpful to see *what exactly* is wrong:

- naming conventions: names of functions should be dash-separated-lowercase-words, so no `Example`, but `example`.
- already mentioned [`def`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/def) inside `defn`. `Def` creates a global variable, don't use it inside any other definitions. If you need to create some variables inside function, use [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let).
- *integer variable* and *float variable*. Clojure uses `long` and `double` and created variables will have exactly these types- you can check it yourself with function [`type`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/type).
- repeated [`println`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/println) (it'll work, but you can also use [`clojure.string/join`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join) with [`vector`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector) and only one `println` to get the same result)

Improved code:

```
(defn example []
  (let [x 1
        y 1.25
        str1 "Hello"]
    (println (clojure.string/join
               "\n"
               [x (type x) y (type y) str1]))))

(example)

=>

1
class java.lang.Long
1.25
class java.lang.Double
Hello
```

Comment: I run this and nothing gets printed out other than the namespace and the function with #' at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a definition inside a function.

You need to declare these symbols (variable in other langs) outside. Something like that.

(ns com.play

```
ground.core
  (:gen-class))

(def x 1)
(def y 1.25)
(def str1 "Hello")

(defn Example []
  (println x)
  (println y)
  (println str1))

(Example)
```

So, when you do it, you're declaring `x` `y` and `str1` as global and it's not a good practice.

To keep the context of these symbols only inside the function, you need to use the `let` approach.

```
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn Example []
  (let [x 1
        y 1.25
        str1 "Hello"]
    (println x)
    (println y)
    (println str1)))

(Example)
```

An extra tip is to avoid using camel-case as a way of declaration naming.
Consider to use kebab-case :)

```
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn example-function []
  (let [x 1
        y 1.25
        str1 "Hello"]
    (println x)
    (println y)
    (println str1)))

(example-function)
```